# compiling g++ programs

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I have the gcc installed. I can compile C programs. But I cannot compile C++ programs. If I write g++ on comd line, it says program not installed. I tried  s`udo apt-get install g++` It gives me a very long output, saying things like some packages cannot be installed and some are newest version already. Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It says `build-essential package is not available.` Also tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Nothing works.
What to do now? How to compile g++ programs

Comment: g++ is the right package.


    dpkg --search g++ | grep bin
    g++: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
    g++-4.9: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.9
    g++: /usr/bin/g++
    g++-4.9: /usr/bin/g++-4.9

You should resolve issues of your installation of g++. What is the error ?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu **version**?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable main and universe repositories.

See how to do that in this question:

[Problem installing build-essential on 14.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520999/problem-installing-build-essential-on-14-04-1-lts)